# How to enter "ESC" key in a Python script?

Tags: python

I have logined to a CentOS machine using below Python script:

```
import paramiko

username = input('Username: ')
password = input('Password: ')

ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh_client.connect(hostname='192.168.30.129',username=username,password=password,look_for_keys=False)

remote_connection = ssh_client.invoke_shell()
remote_connection.send("mkdir test\n")
remote_connection.send("vi test.txt\n")
remote_connection.send("test\n")
remote_connection.send(":wq\n")
output = remote_connection.recv(65535).decode('ascii')
print (output)

ssh_client.close
```

What I did with this script:

1. Login to the CentOS machine using paramiko
2. Create a folder called 'test'
3. Create a text file called 'test.txt' using vi and type 'test' in the file.
4. Type ':wq' in order to save the change I made in 'test.txt' and quit vi.

Step 1 to 3 work perfectly for me, but I couldn't get step 4 done because I don't how to hit "esc" button to enter the Normal Mode of Vi before I'm able to type :wq.

So my question is: How to enter "ESC" key in a Python script?

Comment: You can use the `\xnn` sequence with the ASCII code of ESC

Comment: BTW, on the last line, you probably want to call the close method: `ssh_client.close()`

Comment: why not use `echo test > test.txt` command

Comment: Thanks Baum, I tried remote_connection.send("\xnn"), it returned “UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte” error.

Comment: Thanks pouria farhadi, using echo works, but I still prefer editing a file using vi.

Comment: You need to put the ASCII code in place of the `nn`

Comment: So, that'd be `\x1b`

Comment: Using `vi` from within Paramiko is borderline insane. Is there a particular reason you want to use a tool designed specifically for interactive use?

Comment: Many thanks Baum, \x1b did the trick!

Comment: @martineau I have reopened this question; this is unrelated to detecting keypresses in Python. I would have thought there'd be a duplicate about how to represent the _Esc_ character in a string, too, but I could not find one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420671/whats-the-vt100-escape-code-for-the-esc-keyboard-key-itself asks basically the same question, but the answers don't answer that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question lacks an important step; you need to type <kbd>Esc</kbd> before you type `:wq`. This is just another character, though it's not a printable character; it can be represented e.g. with the hex escape code `\x1b` (similarly, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> is `\x01`, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd> is `\x02`, etc; <kbd>Esc</kbd> is also sometimes represented as <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>[</kbd>.)

However, using `vi` to create a file programmatically is extremely odd; you're much better off using a simple redirection like

```sh
echo "test" >test.txt
```

If you need to write multiple lines, `printf` is convenient:

```sh
printf '%s\n' 'hello' '' 'world' >test.txt
```

writes the three lines "hello", an empty line, and "world" to the file.